# Unexpected behavior of lock in C# with Parallel.For

Tags: c#, locking, parallel.for

doing the following

```
static object aggLock = new object();
static long max = 10000000;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        double totalSumSeq = 0;
        double totalSumLock = 0;

        // Seq
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            double y = Math.Sqrt(i);
            totalSumSeq += y;
        }

        ...
}
```

returns the expected 21,081,849,486.4393.

Using

```
        // Parallel.For(from, to, init, body, finally);
        Parallel.For(0, max, () => 0.0, (i, pls, y) => // (LoopVariable, ParallelLoopState, ThreadLocalVariable)
        {
            y = Math.Sqrt(i);
            return y;
        },
        partSum =>
        {
            lock (aggLock)
            {
                totalSumLock += partSum;
            }
        }
        );
```

instead I get totally different values, like in race conditions. Why?

Comment: What is in aggLock?

Comment: See first code block: = new object().

Comment: Sample from the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd460703(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should aggregate the partial sums when returning the iteration value:

```
Parallel.For(0, max, () => 0.0, (i, pls, y) => 
 {
    //y = Math.Sqrt(i);
    int r = y + Math.Sqrt(i);  // a + to  fix it
    return r;
 }, ...
```

`y` is initialized to 0.0 with `() => 0.0` and it resurfaces at the end of a partition as `partSum`. But you only used the last value of the partition.

An alternative using PLinq (but Range() won't accept `long` for max) :

```
        double plinqSum = Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int) max)
            .AsParallel()
            .Sum(i => Math.Sqrt(i));  // or just  .Sum(Math.Sqrt);
```

This `.AsParallel().Sum()` bit is essentially what you're building with the `Parallel.For()`

Comment: ... or just use another, simpler overload `Parallel.For(long, long, Action<long>)`

Comment: But that will only let you sum by locking for _each_ value of `i`, missing the point a little.

Comment: Or `return y + Math.Sqrt(i);`. There's no need to update the incoming parameter value just to then separately return it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - that is a very trivial and irrelevant notational difference. I wanted to stay as close as possible to the original code.

Comment: I thought the OP may have focussed on the fact that the third parameter is the "thread local variable" and thus have somehow concluded that they have to *update* that variable. It's minor, but I thought it might be worth mentioning. Otherwise, I can't see why they were assigning to that variable at all.